# EXEC select query not working with temp table SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this SQL Server 2005 Puzzle

The following code doesn't work

```
 DECLARE @tmp TABLE  (ID  int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , strDateTime varchar(50)) 
 INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES('1/2/13') 

 DECLARE @x varchar(1000) 
 SET @x = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tmp ;
 EXEC (@x)
```

I get the following error

> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@tmp".*

If I do this

```
SET @x = 'SELECT * FROM  @tmp ' ;
```

I get this error

> *Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>
>   Must declare the table variable "@tmp".*

Well what I was really trying to do is passing dynamic column name to a select statement and I found that I didn't like that either

Can someone guide me what I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: `@tmp` is a table variable not a scalar variable so not valid for concatenating into a string. It would be out of scope for dynamic SQL anyway. Why do you need dynamic SQL? `SELECT * FROM @tmp` should work fine.

Comment: i update my answer i should explain this from the begging i was trying to pass in dynamic column name to a select statment from TEMP table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A table variable is only valid in the scope within which it is created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx):

> A table variable behaves like a local variable. It has a well-defined
>   scope. This is the function, stored procedure, or batch that it is
>   declared in.

To do this, you'll need to use a temporary table:

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID  int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , strDateTime varchar(50)) 
 INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('1/2/13') 

 DECLARE @x varchar(1000) 
 SET @x = 'SELECT * FROM #tmp';
 EXEC (@x)
```

Comment: does this create table in the database ? i don't want to do this

Comment: @MinaGabriel Both `CREATE TABLE #tmp` and `DECLARE @tmp TABLE` end up creating temporary tables in `tempdb`

Comment: I though this will create new Table in the database

Comment: how can i delete this table '

Comment: @MinaGabriel It will be dropped automatically when it goes out of scope... otherwise, you can explicitly drop it using `DROP TABLE #tmp`.

Comment: Check for existence if you want to be sure, but @MichaelFredrickson is right, the minute your query scope ends, this table is dropped automatically (when you close that SSMS script, or end your current connection)

`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#tmp')) DROP TABLE #tmp`